# How can I obtain datasets about human poses?

Tags: dataset

Lots of machine learning tutorials always mention about the identification of hand written numbers or cats or dogs, and there is always a prebuilt dataset for training. **But no one said that how to build that dataset**.

Now we want to build our own model about human poses identification. We know how to train, how to inference, and how to integrate it to our project sources. But the most difficult task we seem is how to obtain **LOTS** human pose images and mark them with correct tags to train.

Would someone kindly show us a way to achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for a dataset, or asking about how to build your own dataset? If the former, could you add why googling "human pose dataset" does not give results you are interested in - what is wrong for instance with http://human-pose.mpi-inf.mpg.de/ - the first result when I google that? There are a few different ways to represent pose, and perhaps your problem requires one specific way - could you clarify what you need in your dataset?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I browse that site and that is almost meet my requirements, but the image quantities is too small to train a confidentable model.